# button not working with JS code

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have been trying to make this function work and after analyzing debugging it looks like for some reason when clicking the button, this code is never reached; can you please check:

```
$(document).on("ready", function () {

$('#btnSearch').on('click', function () {
    GetUserByNC($("#txtnumeroCuenta").val());
});
```

Names and everything else looks fine; I checked and js file is loaded correctly.

Comment: The code shown has a syntax error, it is missing a closing `})`. Is that a copy/paste error just in your question, or is the `})` missing from your real code too? Assuming your real code doesn't have that problem, is the `#btnSearch` element created dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Use event [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

You could try like this

```
$(document).on('click','#btnSearch', function () {
    GetUserByNC($("#txtnumeroCuenta").val());
});
```